# How to Animate a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Can someone just quickly tell me what I'm doing wrong: it's probably a pretty simple mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Animation Bullshit</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="moving_header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h1>DELL Computers</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#moving_header").mouseover(function() {
        $("#moving_header").animate({
        margin-top: 0px;
        }, 5000);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I mouse over the div, nothing happens at all. I want it to slide down from the top of the screen.

UPDATE:
Here's what I've got now. Still doesn't work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random Animation Bullshit</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="moving_header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h1>DELL Computers</h1>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#moving_header").mouseover(function() {
        $("#moving_header").animate({
        marginTop: '0px';
        }, 5000);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: Here's my CSS:

```
#moving_header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #FF6600;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#menu {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 20px;
}

#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Cutive Mono, sans;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#moving_header h1 {
    font-family: Cutive Mono, sans;
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery??

Comment: you haven't included jquery on the page

Comment: get rid of that semicolon after `margin-top: 0px;` - also, I think both of those need to be strings, so wrap both `margin-top` and `0px` with quotes

Comment: The code looks good.  What is margin-top before mouseover?  If 0px, nothing happens when animating to 0px;

Comment: Also, need "marginTop" instead of margin-top and "0px" need quotes.

Comment: Yes, rfornal is right, you're adding no margin. Please check the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/s26gfb7a/), for a working demo. Also 5 sec. animation time is a bit too long.

Comment: AWolf, I tried your fiddle as well. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That is because jQuery isn't in your file. Here's the modified version of the header with jQuery added:

```
<head>
<title>Random Animation Bullshit</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

EDIT: Use this instead

```
<head>
<title>Random Animation Bullshit</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: You should use marginTop: '0px', instead of margin-top: 0px

Comment: Nope, still not doing anything.

Comment: What's the initial position of the div?

Comment: Take into account the initial margin is 0 and I'm adding 100px to it.

Comment: Made a change to the initial answer, realised I gave you the wrong link, my bad!

Comment: I just tried your fiddle too. Still not working! What could be going on? I'll post my CSS as well. Maybe it's a problem with that.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle with your css as well, it seems to be working correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/c66L9j08/

Comment: I just cleared my browser cache, didn't do anything. I also tried on every other browser I could think of - no difference. Your fiddle works for me as well. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you tell me what are you getting on the console? Any errors?

Comment: Console? I'm using Notepad++. May be equipped with a console, but I've never used it before.

Comment: I mean the console of your web browser. Normally you pull it out with alt + cmd + i on a mac and alt + ctrl + i on windows/linux.

Comment: Aaaah. I've got a Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
animation.html:22 and Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined... Know what that means?

Comment: Yeap, it is not finding jQuery. Did you check the edit I did to the initial answer? I gave you the wrong link and edited it for the right one. Change <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> with <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, I updated that. I also tried a completely different link of my own, which didn't work either. I'm wondering if it's a network error. I'm running of my school wifi.

Comment: Why don't you try it when you get to another network? You can see it works as expected in the fiddle I gave you.